# Return Ajax response after the futures completes

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, akka, actor

i have a problem doing my internship. I have to execute an Ajax POST to a Servlet, which sends a message to an actor through a future and returns the response after the futures completes. Is this possible?

Example:

```java
public void resultRetrieveAsync(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {    

    ActorRef sender = i create this sender someway;
    Future<Object> future = Patterns.ask(sender, "HELLO", 5000);
    //Let's imagine another actor has to respond "Hello Sender"

    String hello = (String)Await.result(future, new Timeout(5000).duration());

    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    out.print(hello);
}
```

How can i smartly avoid the use of that "Await"? Imagine "moving" the waiting time far away from the server and much more on the Actor based application.

For the Ajax "side" imagine the simplest Ajax post you can.

I can't figure how to do this! 
Thanks in advance guys!

Answer (score 1):

**SYNCHRONOUS**

`future.get()` would wait on the response to come back and provide you with the result.

```
String hello = (String) future.get();
```

NOTE: `.get()` method makes the call synchronous.

**ASYNC**

You can use

```
CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(/* call your AJAX endpoint here */)  
                 .thenAccept(/* display your HELLO String here */);
```

Hope this points you in the right direction!

**EDIT**

Here is an example JS function that will do an AJAX POST:

```
function myFunction() {    
     $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'SOME_URL',   //Make sure you put the correct endpoint URL here!                
        data: MY_DATE, //form data, or whatever here            
        contentType: 'application/json',
        success: function(data) { 
                    //DO SOMETHING HERE AFTER YOU GET THE RESPONSE                        
                 },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    //Do something on ERROR here                            
               }
    });

}
```

After that, just call `myFunction()` on a `click` event or whatever.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer @Mechkov, 
Can you supply me an example of a script if you have time?

Comment: thanks a lot! I'll give it a look, but i'm a bit worried about the fact taht ComparableFuture is a Java 8 Feature and i'm forced to use Java 7.

Comment: You cannot use it then. It's a Java 8 feature.

Comment: Do you think there's not another way? Like a workaround?

Comment: CompletableFuture uses Threads right? So, you can come up with an elaborate way to make it work ...